# JQuery Masonry: Append Images through ajax

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-masonry

I have lots of images loading through ajax.I am using masonry and lazy load plugin to show images.Loading all images through one ajax call causing issues and page got stuck till all the images get arranged, So I am loading 20 images in first ajax call and than immediate after this one-by-one ajax request get 10 images in each call and append through masonry append.

```
function getMorePhotos () {
    $.ajax({
            type    : "POST",
            url     : site_url+'controller/ajax_get_photos',
            data    : ,
            complete: function(response)
                    {
                        if (response.responseText != '0' )
                        {
                            getMorePhotos();
                        }                       
                    },
            success : function(response) 
                {
                    if (response == '0' || response == '') {
                        
                    } else {
                        var temp = $(response).get();
                        temp.forEach(function( element, index ) {
                            $item = $(element);
                            $('#allPhoto1').find('ul.ins-view').append($item).masonry( 'appended', $item );
                            $item.find("img.lazy").lazyload({
                                effect : "fadeIn",
                                threshold : 100
                            });

                        });
                        
                    }
                }
        });
}
```

This is the method calls after first request complete.

Now the problem is: first image continuous blink till last ajax request complete.

I feel that this is not a good solution.Can anyone suggest?
[image]

I have `<ul> <li>` structure having four column.(See image)

Comment: can you give us a demo jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved the issues.I was missing `true` here

```
$('#allPhoto1').find('ul.ins-view').append($item).masonry( 'appended', $item, true);
```

Setting true animates appended image from bottom.

One more thing I have done is calculate image height and set it in image css before appending, it will avoid overlapping.I will post the live demo soon.

Thanks for valuable time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use imagesLoaded (http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) with masonry if you have images in your items.
The following code worked for me

```
//Initiate  maosnry
$container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){ 
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    }); 
});

//and on ajax call append or prepend more items
var $data = $(data).filter(".items");   
$container.prepend($data).imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry( 'prepended', $data, true );
});
```